# Does Canon have an AF assist light on camera?

Tags: canon, autofocus, focus

I have a 70D and a T2i, and none of them turn on an AF assist light when focusing. I also have a YN465 which has an AF assist led and it works perfectly in both cameras. I believe the camera would have a similar light (like happens in nikon) using the same bulb that blinks when shooting with the timer, but maybe I'm wrong. The camera menu mentions an "IR assist beam", and I don't know if this is it, but at least it doesn't light up.

I looked for any video showing this light turned on, but couldn't find it. Can anybody give me an idea? Hope I was clear.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The EOS cameras with pop-up flash, such as the 70D and T2i, use the pop-up flash when focus assist is needed. To use it without the flash firing when the photo is exposed you select "disable flash firing" under the flash control menu while selecting "enable AF assist beam firing" under the AF menu or Custom functions menu, depending on the specific camera model. You may need to press the flash button on the front of the camera to manually open the flash. The flash will fire several low-powered pulses to assist focus but will not fire when the shutter is opened. This would include all EOS APS-C DSLR models.

EOS cameras without a pop-up flash require an external flash or a wireless flash controller equipped with a near-infrared AF assist lamp in order to provide an assist light for focussing. This would include all full frame and APS-H models.

The "IR Assist Beam" mentioned in menu items refers only to an external flash or wireless flash controller that includes a near-infrared AF assist lamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. I'd have sweared that that bulb did the same as in Nikon, but I was wrong. I'll have to use a torch or a laser to achieve this.

Comment: There are compact/superzoom/bridge cameras made by many manufacturers that use the same lamp, or at least the same hole in the body, for both an AF assist lamp and a self-timer indicator. But they are usually not that powerful and don't have a very long effective reach. All they often do is distract many subjects who are performing or competing in athletic competitions.

Comment: So the answer is "no", right?