# Manual settings on Canon EOS 450D not writing

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, camera-settings, canon-450d

I'm struggling to work out what is going on. Photos "taken" using any of the manual settings on my Canon EOS 450D result in a delay (as though I have set the timer) and then no image is written to the card. I have it set to take photos in L/RAW and have previously used the same setup successfully (several years ago). I can take photos using the Full Auto setting but then I can't turn off the flash and my photos are getting overexposed (plus, don't want to use full auto!).

Any idea what could be wrong? Cheers

Comment: Are you using manual focus? Or, if using AF, do you hear the bip that confirm that focus is acquired?  It could just be the camera that cannot autofocus due to bad lighting, in which case [see this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82923/does-canon-have-an-af-assist-light-on-camera). Otherwise did you try with quality set to RAW+L in Av or Tv modes? Did you try with another SD card?

Comment: Is mirror lockup enabled?

Comment: Hey guys, I have used both manual and AF. Yes to bip! The camera shutter goes, then there is a delay, then no image is written. Not a lighting issue. I have tried in M, Av and Tv modes with the same result. Haven't tried a different SD card but there's no issue with photos writing to the card on any of the automatic settings.

Comment: So, it was the mirror lockup! Thank you Michael. I did use these settings with the remote control previously, which must be what it's still doing. When I press the shutter button twice, it takes the picture. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you might have enabled mirror lockup and forgot to turn it back off.

At one shutter button press, the mirror goes up and remains there for up to 30 seconds, but the shutter does not open. After 30 seconds the mirror lockup will 'time out' and the mirror will drop back down without any image having been captured.

It takes another press of the shutter button to actually release the shutter and take a photo.

Comment: So, it was the mirror lockup! Thank you Michael. I did use these settings with the remote control previously, which must be what it's still doing. When I press the shutter button twice, it takes the picture. THANK YOU!

Comment: It was indeed the mirror lock up! Thank you very much.